# Export blog entries from Blogger

Tags: export, blogger

How can I export all blog entries with uploaded images from Blogger. There is an export feature, but it exports an Atom file with image referencing the uploaded images.

I would like to export the full content with uploaded images included inline.

Comment: export to what format?

Comment: @akira - some xml plus images zipped would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

[ZoundryRaven](http://www.zoundryraven.com) allow you get all your content from blogger. 
After syncronization
in folder Zoundry Raven/profiles/{youraccount}/datastore you will find your post in xml format.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's possible. It depends why do you need to back-up. If you just want a copy of the content, try a site cloner (e.g.: [SiteSucker](http://www.sitesucker.us/mac.html)). If you want to restore it or import it elsewhere, you are out of luck because as far as I know, the xml files for template and content are the only things that can be restored to Blogger. However, the images are stored by Picasa, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a blogger account to test how it does, but [Backupify](http://www.backupify.com/) will backup Blogger. If its anything like the twitter and facebook backups, it will give you access to an archive of everything as well as individual files for separate entities (mention, replies, DMs for twitter, status updates, photos, events from facebook)

Answer (score 0):

Follow Following steps to export your blog entries as xml [image: Setting Others Tab Preview]

```
 1. Go to Settings > Others Tabs
 2. Then in Blog tools section click on Export blog
 3. A Dialog Box appears, in that clcik on button Download Blog
```

then you can use that xml file at any other blog on blogger, wordpress or any other.

Comment: This doesn't do what the question asked for.   It generates an xml file which has links to the image-file (wherever it's hosted), nto the actual image.

Comment: For Images you can use Data URI.