# How do I export my blog from Blogger?

Tags: blogger

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Export blog entries from Blogger](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2665/export-blog-entries-from-blogger)

Apparently I have used up all of the space that Google will give me for free for photos on my blog but I don't want to delete past posts. How do I export into a format that looks like something readable?

I know how to export from the settings into XML but I don't even know what that is and it sure doesn't look like a blog when you open it.

Answer (score 2):

What do you really want to achieve here?   Removing some blog posts will not free up photo space - and there is in fact no limit to the amount of blog-post material that you can host within Blogger, apart from Photos.

To free up photo space, you need to go into [Picasa web albums](https://picasaweb.google.com) and remove some photos.

But if you don't want to do that, another alternative is to just put new photos into another place (eg FlickR), and link to them from new blog posts.

All that said - do you really want to make a human-readable off-line copy of your blog?   (Again, this is not the same as exporting it, which just creates an XML file which really is only good for computers to read.)

Comment: I just want to have a back up copy of my blog as it is.  I don't want to delete the photos from any of my posts with out having it backed up and I don't know how to do that.  Is it possible to create a pdf file of my blog or something like that?  I don't necessarily want a hard copy right now.  Can you explain how I would link new photos from another place like FlickR?

Comment: To make a backup electronic copy I would suggest a tool like Htrack (www.httrack.com - you need to download it).    Notice that it won't include copies of your photos, videos etc - it will still read them from whatever place they are stored in.

Comment: To use photos stored in another place, you need to upload them there, then get the URL of the photo.   then in blogger's Post Editor, select the "web location" option (I can't remember the exact words, it's the last one on the list).    More here about this:   http://blogger-hints-and-tips.blogspot.com/2010/10/hosting-pictures-outside-of.html