# Is there a way to export the text of blog entries, in Blogger, to individual text-files?

Tags: blogger

I have a friend with a Blogger blog (this one: [PuzzleMad.co.uk](http://puzzlemad.co.uk/)), he wants to create a local archive of the individual entries. Now, exporting produces a large XML file which is fine as far as it goes, but the goal is to create an individual text-file (`.txt` for preference) and *ideally* with a Markdown representation of the content's formatting/structure for each blog-entry (the inclusion of comments is entirely optional and, depends only on the ease of including or removing them).

I suspect that this might involve applying a scripting solution to the exported XML file rather than a feature included within the Blogger engine itself, which is absolutely fine but might potentially be better suited to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

I've looked at a few possibilities, from [a search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bblogger%5D+export+posts) here, including:

- [How do I export my blog from Blogger?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/37786/how-do-i-export-my-blog-from-blogger/37798#37798) - which is more about freeing up photo-space from the linked Picasa service, and has only one answer which mentions that and then suggests the export-as-XML (which is either not a solution to this problem, or is not a *complete* solution to this problem).
- [Export blog entries from Blogger](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2665/export-blog-entries-from-blogger) - doesn't seem to address the problem to which I'm looking for a solution.

Potential solutions:

- [Zoundry Raven](http://www.zoundryraven.com/features.html) - could possibly work, but it seems to be advertised/promoted as a means of managing multiple blogs rather than as a means to download/archive entries *from* blogs.
- [SiteSucker](http://www.sitesucker.us/mac/mac.html) - retrieves and archives, but stops at that point, *doesn't* convert to a text file, certainly doesn't create a Markdown-esque representation of the text, or its HTML structure.
- [Backupify](https://www.backupify.com/) - I'm not quite sure what it does, but doesn't *seem* to, from what I've read, offer a specific means by which exporting-to-text is supported.

As noted, I suspect the end-result will be some form of parsing of the XML, using a scripting language, but if it's at all possible he'd prefer to avoid that, but is willing if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no capability to do what you want within Blogger. Both their standard export, as well as the Google Takeout export produce XML.

The only other option I can think of is some kind of screen-scraper. But TBH, scripting over the XML would probably be easier to do.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I expected (albeit clearly not what I'd hoped).